# Java is acting like I've got pointers. Why?

Tags: java, pointers, reference

I'm building an application using java.swing. I've got a main panel, a grid panel (which displays squares), and a details panel (which brings up the details on each square and lets you edit them). The squares are also objects.

I have the main panel listening for mouse clicks, and if you click on the grid panel, the grid panel will go through it's ArrayList of squares and find which square you clicked on, returning it. This square is passed by the main panel to the display panel, which then sets it's local variable currentSquare equal to the square being passed in.

Where I'm getting confused is that I can edit currentSquare, and the corresponding square in the ArrayList is being edited! I can change the currentSquare's public variables or use a setter to change them, but the effect is the same regardless. While this is the effect that I'm wanting to have happen, I was under the impression that I would have to have some sort of getters/setters to carry the edited currentSquare back to the ArrayList and replace the old square.

My current theory as to why this is happening is that it has something to do with Java's references, since the square is a custom Object, but I'm not certain that this is the case or what caused this. Ultimately I want to know what I did to cause this situation and if it's good/ok programming practice to leave this as it is or build on this (and if I do build on it working like this, how likely is it that it will break).

Comment: Because it has pointers; what it does not have is pointer arithmetic.

Comment: Every object in java is on the heap. You're passing around pointers to those objects as values. There's no objects on the stack or an automatically invoked copy mechanic like in C++. As noted above, you just don't have access to the "raw" pointer ... so they called them "references" which has led to endless holy wars ;)

Comment: @m3th0dman Java does not have function pointers or primitive variable pointers or object pointer pointers either.

Comment: @Jan Dvorak It will have function pointers in version 8 only they will be called lambda expressions; you are right, it does not have primitive variable pointers but it does have object pointers only they are called references in Java. In fact you can only access an object via a reference (which is like a pointer, it holds as value the memory address of the object). As I have said in the above comment, what you do not have is pointer arithmetic meaning that you cannot change the address of your object (unless you use some tricks from the Unsafe class).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Java, when you call a method with an object, you're not sending a copy of the object, but rather a reference to it. Both the caller and the calleee will refer to the same object and the object will be eligible for garbage collection once all references to it disappear.

Java is called "pass-by-value" because the references themselves are values, just like the primitives are values. When you're calling a method with an object, you're sending the address of the object as a parameter, not a copy of the object. You don't have access to the value of the address, you can only access the object referred to by it. Example:

```
import java.util.*;

class Test { 
    private static void test(Map<String, String> a, int b) {
        a.put("test", "def");
        b = 10; 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> a = new HashMap<String, String>();
        a.put("test", "abc");

        int b = 5;

        test(a, b); 

        System.out.println(a);
        System.out.println(b);
    }   
}
```

```
{test=def}
5
```

The above compiles into something like:

```
test(0x123456, 5);
```

Comment: See, I think this is where I'm getting confused. I've heard people describe Java as a pass-by-value, and in my mind, pass-by-value means you make a copy of an object and give it out. Passing by reference makes more sense with what I'm seeing.

Comment: It is pass-by-value. The value is a memory location on the heap not the object itself.

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide It's not pass by reference in that (as a simple example) `f` in `f(variable)` cannot change which object `variable` points at. It's also not pass by value in that objects are not copied, only references are. Also note that "reference" here means something entirely unrelated to "pass by reference". See also: Numerous Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Everything is passed as a reference except for primitives. And keep in mind that a string is immutable

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide, added clarification.

Comment: So, even though I copied the square to a local variable, that local variable still has the same address on the heap, and that's why it all works. Got it!

Comment: @Dr.Cyanide, something like that. You haven't copied the square, you copied its address. If you want to copy the square itself, you need to clone it explicitly, which will result in another square being created, and the value holding this new, cloned square, will contain another address, different from that of the first square.